# How to type hint a custom class

Tags: python, object, types, type-hinting

I have a custom class, lets call it Cust

```
Class Cust:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

how do I type hint an instance of this class? Eg, i want to do

```
    def method(self, other: Cust):
        ...
```

I have tried `other: Cust`, `other: type(Cust)` and `other: typings.Type[Cust]` but all have returned `NameError: Cust is not defined`.

Comment: You can use quotes.

Comment: In 3.11, we should have the [`Self` type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) to address this.